# Backreference to optional ex

Tags: regex

i know the difference between two expressions
/(A?)B/ vs /(A)?B/

if there is no A matched

/(A?)B/  = matches B and  captures **`""`**

/(A)?B/  = matches B and does not capture anything

What does the highlighted captured text mean? It's not a space or word character .Isn't that just equal to nothing

Comment: The empty string is not *nothing*. It's the empty string.

Comment: It is equal to existence of a capturing group. FYI `B` is never *captured*. The correct term for `B` is *match*.

Comment: Also note that in ECMAScript the regexps are identical, as both will have an empty string in Group 1.

Comment: Can you specify the language/tool that you are using? As Wiktor Stribiżew said, in different languages the regex might behave differently.

Comment: @Sweeper Well not any specific but PCRE